# Do you get Xamarin.Forms for free in VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

It's been a lot of talk, but I can't seem to find any reference to it... But I'm under the impression that since xamarin is tighter incorporated in VS2015 you get the Forms without paying for the indie level?

Is that right? Only for WP platform?

Comment: No. Integrated just means more wizards, not a free license.

Comment: That was boring. I was tripping to get started with Xamarin. I don't bother to learn three ways to code the UI with the other project types. Forms was an opportunity to get my app released on Android and/or IOS. But really I don't care so I'm sticking to universal apps.

Comment: In time given the closer partnership of Xamarin and MS, Univerisal Apps will generate for Android and iOS, but not yet.

Comment: I found out that it actually works for Windows Phone! You get a nagging set of "update your android/ios lisence" but if you unload them and set the Windows Phone as your startup you can run it! Now... how do I make it ignore the lisence (as Im not building for Android or IOS anyway)

Comment: Can't you simply remove the projects or unload as you've done? It's easy to add them back. Or... just copy the .sln file to another and remove iOS/Android from that solution. Also if you are only targeting WinPhone and Windows 8, I would use Universal API not Xamforms.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms

Since it is even available on NuGet, you can read the Software License Agreement attached so as to better understand the Dos and Don'ts. Unfortunately I am not a lawyer so I won't be able to interpret the license in more details.

Note that technically what you get is only the library, but without the underlying Xamarin platforms (Xamarin.iOS/Xamarin.Android) you won't be able to use the library on iOS and Android.